# A request to test the responsiveness of the React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am testing an application written in React.js for responsiveness on mobile devices. Hence my request to you, to test the application from this angle and share your thoughts on what can be improved. Certainly I want to improve the performance of the application, so that it loads faster. Is it enough to reduce the weight of photos and add lazyloading atribute to some photos?

[Application link](https://vigorous-tesla-ec685c.netlify.app/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it not actually a question, it's like a user just want to take feedback of his/her application thought this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS IS TESTED ON A SMALL WINDOW SIMULATING MOBILE CLIENTS

Two problems here on this part. First, the text in the button is not properly displayed, and secondly, not sure if it is done on purpose, but the design of overlapping white text on a light background makes it a bit hard for people to see.
[image]

Over here, the line is sitting on top of the button on smaller screens and it is hovering over some of the content. Say you are clicking that button in the center, it doesn't work because there is this line on top of it, and that might not be something you want:

[image]

And here, your image is overflowing on the x axis:

[image]

Finally, this navigation bar on mobile devices is positioned absolutely on top of the screen, and I'm not sure if that's what you were planning to do, I recommend sticking it on to the screen such that even when the user scrolls, it's still there, fully exposed and what this does is that, the user doesn't have to scroll all the way to the top to find that navigation bar.

[image]

But, overall, this looks quite good and the color scheme really suites the theme.